# App goes dark when loading view controller from Custom framework storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I made a custom framework using pods, and below is my code structure. The issue that I am facing is I am unable to instantiate View Controller from Login.storyboard. Whenever I am trying to do that, My app screen turns dark.
This is how I am calling it in SceneDelegate,

```
   func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
   
    let bundle = Bundle(identifier: "com.NewCustomKt")
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Login", bundle: bundle)
    window.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginPageVC") as? LoginPageVC
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Things I tried,

1. deleted main.storyboard
2. Created a new bundle for login.sotryboard but it did not work as bundle comes out nil.
3. currently code is not crashing but apps turn dark.

This is my NewCustomKt podspec file

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|

 spec.name         = "NewCustomKt"
 spec.version      = "0.0.1"
 spec.summary      = "A short description of NewCustomKt."

 spec.description  = "Hello world i"
               

 spec.homepage     = "http://EXAMPLE/NewCustomKt"
 spec.license      = "MIT (example)"
 spec.license      = { :type => "MIT", :file => "FILE_LICENSE" }

 spec.author             = { "Hirak Borah" => "hirak.borah@go-mmt.com" }
 spec.platform     = :ios

 spec.source       = { :path => "." }
 spec.source_files  = "NewCustomKt", "NewCustomKt/Classes/**/*.{h,m,swift}"
 spec.exclude_files = "NewCustomKt/Exclude"
 spec.public_header_files = "NewCustomKt/**/*.h"

 spec.resource_bundles = {
 'NewCustomKt' => [
  'NewCustomKt/Classes/**/*.{xib,storyboard,json,xcdatamodel,xcassets}'
 ]
 }
end
```

[image]

Comment: check if the storyboard is nil, I think that your problem is the bundle.

Comment: @cristian_064 storyboard is not nil.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue which is a silly one :< , I forgot to assign self.window to the current window.